# How do I serve a webpage on a local PC without revealing my IP-address to end users?

Tags: privacy, webserver, ip, web-service, websites

Are there any ways to serve a webpage locally without revealing IP to end users?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Where are usesr? Where they send requests to? How is it related to your local host?

Comment: Also, can you tell us what your end goal is?  This sounds like it could potentially be an AB problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Why can't the end user see the IP address?

Answer (score 9):

In order to hide your IP address from users you need to make sure that they don't access your server directly, i.e. put some kind of reverse proxy in between. For public sites this can be done by putting a CDN like Cloudflare in front of it. For internally hosted sites this can by done by using services like [ngrok or similar](https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling).

Comment: Could also run a hidden service on Tor.

Comment: Iot is riddled with third party offerings for this. Largely due to CGNAT, but this use case still applies.

Comment: I heard that in case where both you (the server) and the person who recieves a webpage (client) are acomodated in the same country (or city/town, I'm not sure) the request goes directly (as there's no point in routing it through a CDN server first)

Comment: @infinitieunique: *"there's no point in routing"* - it does not work this way. The client looks up the hostname - which should resolve to the CDN. Since it resolves to the CDN the client will access the CDN. There might in theory a more efficient way to reach the server but the client does not know this way since it does not know the servers real IP address (since you hide this).