# How would I communicate with my computer from a remote server when I'm using a VPN?

Tags: network, windows, privacy, vpn, internet

I have a computer at home. It's connected to the Internet. I use OpenVPN on Windows 10 to auto-connect to a VPN at startup.

Now, I would like for a remote computer to make some sort of network connection to my PC to receive and send data. For example, via a TCP/IP socket at port 12345.

But if I give the IP address which I appear to have if I check on a website, to the remote computer, and it tries to send a bunch of data to that IP address on port 12345 with TCP/IP, how would that work? Some VPN server in a data center would receive this connection and probably just drop it. How would it know that it's meant for my computer?

If the answer is to "just use the real IP address of your computer", that would be a violation of privacy and thus security. I do not fully trust the entity that owns the remote computer, and I do not wish for them to have direct access to my computer, or to know my IP address.

Is this technically impossible?

Comment: You need to setup a port forwarding rule with your VPN provider, such that incoming packets on port 12345 at your VPN’s IP address are forwarded to your host.  See https://nordvpn.com/blog/port-forwarding/ for more info.

Comment: From my understanding the ultimate goal you are trying to reach is to make your local computer accessible by others w/o revealing its IP address. Using a VPN for this is the idea you came up with and now you are asking how to implement this idea. So you are asking for Y in a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).   But using a consumer grade VPN isn't the solution for this in the first place because they don't usually offer such a feature. Use instead solutions like [ngrok and others](https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling).

Comment: @mti2935 Well, I don't use NordVPN, but it's not a good sign that they go out of their way to mention that they are "incompatible with" port-forwarding...

Comment: Also, what @SteffenUllrich says makes me believe that no VPN (which I could afford and want to use) will support this... :/

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You seem to link to a software project. How would that help me exactly, since this is not about software on my computers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I serve a webpage on a local PC without revealing my IP-address to end users?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244677/how-do-i-serve-a-webpage-on-a-local-pc-without-revealing-my-ip-address-to-end-us)

Comment: @Cegelka: it is referencing ngrok and other tools there. I recommend that you look into these. It is basically a internet located reverse proxy (externally accessible and your IP hidden) and a local client on your system connects your internal server with this reverse proxy so that no port forwarding in your router is needed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have looked at that page, but all it does is talk a bunch of stuff which seems completely unrelated to what I'm asking for, *and* they advertise a bunch of privacy-destroying entities such as CloudFlare (ugh...) and encourage people to use closed-source, signup-only nonsense.

Comment: it is technically possible and [at least one commercial vpn provider offers the service](https://mullvad.net/en/help/port-forwarding-and-mullvad/) - the way in which you obtain and then communicate the public-facing ip is application-specific, and could be dynamic-dns or some other mechanism (i suggest against fixing the ip addy in your app, as this will prove to be problematic over time for various reasons)

Comment: The only thing the VPN would be accomplishing is to hide the IP of your home internet connection and maybe add as much firewall as a normal home router. It gives no other security or privacy benefits if you would let them *"make some sort of network connection to my PC"*

Comment: So you don't want to know how to do this, you want a step-by-step technical guide only using technologies that you approve of? This isn't a security question. This is a basic networking question.